Data related to the response is being filtered and body is not displayed despite various attempts to set it up
I would like the log to include all information regarding requests and responses including their bodies.
Despite the following standard logging configuration, the content of the responses is being filtered, and the body is not displayed.
httpClient.wiretap("outboundLogger", LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL);

In log4j2.xml, I have: <Logger name="outboundLogger" level="DEBUG"/>
Using reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient on DEBUG does not change anything – data are still filtered and there are no bodies.
I have taken several approaches to configure it, unfortunately to no avail. All attempts were made with and withoung wiretap.

Add the following CustomLogger to the config:

public class CustomLoggingHandler extends LoggingHandler {

    public CustomLoggingHandler() {
        super("outboundLogger", LogLevel.DEBUG, ByteBufFormat.SIMPLE);
        System.out.println("Creating outbound custom logger");
    }

    @Override
    protected String format(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String eventName) {
        System.out.println("Format1");
        return super.format(ctx, eventName);
    }

    @Override
    protected String format(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String eventName, Object firstArg, Object secondArg) {
        System.out.println("Format2");
        return super.format(ctx, eventName, firstArg, secondArg);
    }

    @Override
    protected String format(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String event, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Format3");
        if (arg instanceof ByteBuf) {
            ByteBuf msg = (ByteBuf) arg;
            return msg.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        return super.format(ctx, event, arg);
    }

    @Override
    public LogLevel level() {
        return LogLevel.DEBUG;
    }
}

a)
httpClient.doOnChannelInit((observer, channel, remoteAddress) -> channel.pipeline()
          .addFirst(new CustomLoggingHandler()));

b)
httpClient.doOnConnected(conn -> {
                conn.addHandlerFirst(new CustomLoggingHandler());
                conn.addHandlerLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG));
            });


Add the CustomLogger to tcpConfig:

httpClient.tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> {
                tcpClient = tcpClient.doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                                         .addHandlerLast(new CustomLoggingHandler())
                                         );
                return tcpClient;

Besides that, I made many other attempts, but I'll spare listing them as they led nowhere. What intrigues me is that the following config also works (albeit filtered, but still):
httpClient.wiretap(false);
httpClient.doOnConnected(conn -> {
                conn.addHandlerFirst(new CustomLoggingHandler());
            });

But none of the System.out.print gets executed.
When debugging, the logging hander is null, so I have no idea why something is printed to the screen.

https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/3371
